# Searching for multiple orders on admin order list

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i want to search for multiple order numbers so i created this snippet:

```
function woo_multiple_order_search(  $query_vars ) {

global $typenow;
global $wpdb;
global $pagenow;

    if ( 'shop_order' === $typenow && isset( $_GET['s'] ) && 'edit.php' === $pagenow ) {

        $search_term = esc_sql( sanitize_text_field( $_GET['s'] ) );
        
        if (strpos($search_term, '|') == false) 
            return $query_vars;
        $order_ids = explode('|',$search_term);

        $meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR'
        );
        if(is_array($order_ids) && $order_ids) {
            foreach($order_ids as $order_id) {
                $meta_query[] = array(
                    'key' => '_order_number',
                    'value' => $order_id,
                    'compare' => '='
                );
            }
        }   
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'  => -1,
            'post_type'       => 'shop_order',
            'post_status'     => 'any',
            'meta_query'      => $meta_query
        );
        $posts = get_posts( $args ); 
        if ( ! $posts ) return $query_vars;

        foreach($posts as $post){
            
            $query_vars['post__in'][] = $post->ID;
        }

    }
    return $query_vars;

}
add_filter( 'request', 'woo_multiple_order_search', 20 );
```

the logic behind is whenever "|" is detected inside the search string it should check inside a meta_key and return the results.
now i can verify that up to:

```
get_posts( $args );
```

it works as it gives the correct results.
However i can't figure out how to return them to the admin list.
Probably

```
$query_vars['post__in'][] = $post->ID;
```

is incorrect. any ideas?